# Is it possible to export just a constant variable from inside a React function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set the value of an object using an API call and export the result to other classes from inside my app.

This is how I'm trying to do it

```
import {MaterialUIComponentsNavigation} from 'app/main/documentation/material-ui-components/MaterialUIComponentsNavigation';
import {authRoles} from 'app/auth';
import {callTextApi} from "../services/textService/textContext";
import {useState} from "react";

function navigationConfig () {

  console.log("Random");
  return test =  [
    {
      'id'      : 'applications',
      'title'   : 'Applications',
      'type'    : 'group',
      'icon'    : 'apps',
      'children': [
        {
          'id'      : 'dashboards',
          'title'   : 'Dashboards',
          'type'    : 'collapse',
          'icon'    : 'dashboard',
          'children': [
            {
              'id'   : 'analytics-dashboard',
              'title': 'Raaaaaaaaaaaa',
              'type' : 'item',
              'url'  : '/apps/dashboards/analytics'
            },
            {
              'id'   : 'project-dashboard',
              'title': 'Project',
              'type' : 'item',
              'url'  : '/apps/dashboards/project'
            }
          ]
        },
//some more object fields
}
export default navigationConfig;
```

My question is: Is there a way to only export the test variable and not the entire function? 
I need this to be a function because I can't use react hooks inside a constant, that why I am trying to export a constant from inside a function.

The export looks like this

```
navigationConfig() {
  console.log("Random");
  return test = [{
    'id': 'applications',
    'title': 'Applications',
    'type': 'group',
    'icon': 'apps',
    'children': [{
      'id': 'dashbo…
```

When it should be looking like this:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "authentication", title: "Authentication", type: "collapse", icon: "lock", badge: {…}, …}
1: {id: "coming-soon", title: "Coming Soon", type: "item", icon: "alarm", url: "/pages/coming-soon"}
2: {id: "errors", title: "Errors", type: "collapse", icon: "error", children: Array(2)}
3: {id: "invoice", title: "Invoice", type: "collapse", icon: "receipt", children: Array(2)}
4: {id: "maintenance", title: "Maintenance", type: "item", icon: "build", url: "/pages/maintenance"}
5: {id: "pricing", title: "Pricing", type: "collapse", icon: "attach_money", children: Array(3)}
6: {id: "profile", title: "Profile", type: "item", icon: "person", url: "/pages/profile"}
7: {id: "search", title: "Search", type: "collapse", icon: "search", children: Array(2)}
8: {id: "faq", title: "Faq", type: "item", icon: "help", url: "/pages/faq"}
9: {id: "knowledge-base", title: "Knowledge Base", type: "item", icon: "import_contacts", url: "/pages/knowledge-base"}
```

Hopefully the question makes sence.

P.S. I'm still learning React so please don't be too harsh :D

Comment: You can export whatever you want, in your case you want to make a custom-hook refer to react docs

Comment: This question makes no sense. Can't use a React hook inside a constant? You aren't using any React hooks. Please edit to have what you actually want. Also, I've removed the functional programming tag as this has nothing to do with functional programming, please *read* tag descriptions before adding. I've also added the Javascript tag: SO's syntax highlight usually won't work properly unless you include a language tag. As for still learning, don't sweat it: hooks are a brand new API. We're all still learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a variable like so:

```
const data = {};

export default data;
```

Comment: I know, that what I've been doing before but I can't use React hooks inside constant and it has to be a function :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just export the function and call it wherever you want. Don't know if I understood your question correctly.

If you still want to export object and not the function, something like this may work:

```
navigationConfig() {
    // ....
}

const myExport = navigationConfig();

export default myExport;
```

Comment: It has to be an export default function otherwise I can't use react hooks.

Comment: I'm still not able to understand what you're trying to do. How about you try to declare the variable you're trying to export outside the function and export it as well as use it inside the function?

Comment: I'm trying to create an array of objects with data from an API call, as you know I`ll have to use the useEffect hook to update the data but if you I`m not calling the hooks inside a function with the export default keywords it won't work.

Comment: How about you create a separate function which returns a subscription and you subscribe to that function everywhere you want to use the data from the api?
If you're only making the API call once, you can use a promise instead of creating a subscription.